# LaTeX - left align a table (ie not centred) from the preamble?

Tags: latex, formatting, tex

I'm making a document in LaTeX, but I can only change the preamble of the document. Inside this document I have tables, made with the `longtable` environment. By default LaTeX centres each table in the middle of the page. Is there anyway to make the tables be left aligned, given that I can only change the preamble?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://www.fi.infn.it/pub/tex/doc/orig/longtable.pdf)

The optional argument of longtable controls the horizontal alignment of the table. The possible options are [c], [r] and [l], for centring, right and left adjustment, respectively. Normally centring is the default, but this document speciﬁes

```
  \setlength\LTleft\parindent
  \setlength\LTright\fill
```

in the preamble, which means that the tables are set ﬂush left, but indented by the usual paragraph indentation.

Comment: The link to the documentation point to a version of 1996/11/12. On CTAN you will find one of 2004/02/01: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf